# Scroll box around long list of checkbox options

Tags: html, css, checkbox

How would i place a long list of checkbox options around a scrolling windows so that it does not take up large amounts of the page in my php webpage?

thanks.

Comment: Please clarify; do you want the checkboxes inside a scrolling window inside your webpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work.

HTML:

```
<div class="scrollbox">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollbox {
  height:200px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; height: 400px">
    <!-- put your content here -->
</div>
```

Havent tested it, it should be AROUND those lines. Done that before for a UI framework of mine, had a checkbox list and radiolist UI control and used that technique...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Scrolling Checkboxes</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="ScrollCB" style="height:150;width:200px;overflow:auto"> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb1" name="scb1" value="1">As Seen On Tv<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb2" name="scb2" value="2">Back To Basics<<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb3" name="scb3" value="3">Bed Bath &amp; Beyond<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="scb4" name="scb4" value="4">Black and Decker<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb5" name="scb5" value="5">Borch<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb6" name="scb6" value="6">Culsinart<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb7" name="scb7" value="7">Dualit Lite<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb8" name="scb8" value="8">"Easton<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb9" name="scb9" value="9">Euro Cuisine<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb10" name="scb10" value="10">Euro-Pro<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb11" name="scb11" value="11">Farberware<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb12" name="scb12" value="12">Gator<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb13" name="scb13" value="13">Hamilton Beach<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb14" name="scb14" value="14">Hansgrohe<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="scb15" name="scb15" value="15">International Playthings<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="scb16" name="scb16" value="16">Kitchen Aid<br> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```